# Variable declaration space sensitivity in C

Tags: c, pointers, ansi-c

Consider the following ANSI C code:

```
int* var1, var2; //line 1
int *var3, var4; //line 2
int * var5, var6; //line 3
int var7, *var8; //line 4
```

Are lines 1, 2 and 3 functionally equivalent? Does the spacing associated with '*' matter syntactically? Are 'var2', 'var4' and 'var6' also pointers here? Is line 4 legal?

I come from a Java background, so I've grown too comfortable with its verbosity and object-orientedness. Consequently, it's difficult now to gel with the primitivities of C.

Comment: Spacing does not matter, but the `*` goes with the variable identifier, not the type. [Any good C book will cover these basics.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, line 1 to 3 are equivalent.

And no, `var2`, `var4` and `var6` are *not* pointers. Which is why in C the second line is usually preferred since it show the association of the asterisk to the variable (`var3` in your case) a little better.

And lastly, yes line 4 is valid and declared `var7` as a plain `int` variable, and `var8` as a pointer to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Spacing between `*` and `variable name` doesn't matter in `C`. In front of which variable `*` is positioned that variable will be pointer type.

```
int* var1, var2;
```

Here var1 type will be of pointer type & var2 is normal int variable.

```
int *var3, var4;
```

Here var3 type will be of pointer type & var4 is normal int variable.

```
int * var5, var6;
```

Here var5 type will be of pointer type & var6 is normal int variable.

```
int var7, *var8;
```

Here var7 type will be of normal int type & var8 is pointer variable.

Comment: Cool, thank you :)